# While migrating to Android Api level 29, I am getting this error, requestLegacyExternalStorage not found, failed processing manifest

Tags: android, react-native, android-10.0

I have to use requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" for accessing external storage in my react native app,

`````
build.gradle:
   buildToolsVersion = "29.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"````
Manifest:
  <application
        tools:targetApi="29"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:largeHeap="true">````
    
Error:
error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found.
error: failed processing manifest
`````

Comment: I see no problem description in your post. Nor a question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by changing subprojects compilesdkversion to 29